# how to arrange mini music player in single Bottom sheet for Every screen in flutter app

Tags: flutter, animation, bottom-sheet

want to display mini-music-player at bottom of every screen but it would be must bottom sheet so I can animate the position of the image and controller in full screen.

here is my bottom bar item code

```
return Scaffold(
    body: tabs[currentTabIndex],
    backgroundColor: ColorConstants.kBackGround,
    bottomNavigationBar: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          width: 100.w,
          height: 60,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.black38,
          child: Text(
            "Mini Player",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: currentTabIndex,
          elevation: 0,
          onTap: (currentIndex) => setState(() {
            currentTabIndex = currentIndex;
          }),
          selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          selectedItemColor: ColorConstants.kDarkFontColor,
          backgroundColor: ColorConstants.kBackGround,
          showSelectedLabels: false,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: ""),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search), label: ""),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.library_books), label: "")
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I researched about his a little and came across this flutter package which can be used to solve this issue. If someone knows how to achieve this without using the package then please give your suggestion.

[Mini Player: Flutter Package](https://pub.dev/packages/miniplayer)